# French visa Interview After Previous Illegal Travel

Tags: visas, europe, passport-stamps

I am a U.S. citizen applying for a visa with a French company under the long-stay "passeport talent".  I have all the documents from the company that have been approved by the French government.

Last summer, I had an internship for another French company (< 3 months), for which I had a work contract signed and approved by the French government, but I did not have a visa (negligence on my part, since I thought I did not need it for such a short internship).

When my employer discovered I had not applied for a visa, they made some kind of contact with the French government to absolve themselves of liability, though I am not sure exactly which steps were taken.  I was never actually able to obtain a visa, given that I was already in France at this point, but my employer told me the steps they took had resolved the issue.

I imagine during the visa interview, they will see I have in my passport stamps indicating a 90 day stay in France, and presumably will want details about that.  What is my best course of action for explaining myself?

Comment: Just the truth. It's already done, you committed the transgression and supposedly it was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you think that's going to reduce my chances of acceptance significantly?

Comment: I can only hope that given that I'm applying for a long-stay work visa and not a tourist visa, I don't pose much risk to the system, so they will not give me too much trouble.  Thanks!